# Angularfire get id of duplicate elements from list

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to merge one known element with another from an AngularFireList which have the same code and condition field but different keys in the list. I can not find a proper solution to return the id of an element if it has a duplicate in a list.

My items list is declared as follow:

```
this.activeServ.depoMessage.subscribe(item => {
  return this.items = this.db.list('/Depozite/' + item + '/Items').snapshotChanges();
});
```

And my find function as this:

```
findData(item: Item, items) {
items.subscribe(snapshots => {
  snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.key !== item.key) {
      if (snapshot.payload.val().Code === item.code && snapshot.payload.val().Condition === item.condition) {
        console.log(snapshot.key);
        return snapshot.key;
      }
    }
  });
});}
```

Tried all the possible ways I could find to modify the findData function to return the item with the key modified, but in vain.

Please help!

Comment: This question is super unclear, what exactly are you trying to achieve with findData? Also you aren't returning anything as subscribe is async, do you instead mean to be mapping/filtering on the Observable?

Comment: lets say i have 2 elements in the database with different conditions, chairs for example, they are identical, one is damaged and one is used, and their condition is specified in the database. I want upon changing ones condition to find if there exists another with the same characteristics, if it does then increase the quantity. That's what i actually want to do.